# Can't get CalendarExtender in Ajax toolkit

Tags: asp.net, calendar, asp.net-ajax, toolkit

i'm trying to use an Ajax Toolkit and specific a CalendarExtender and it's not working. There is no errors, but just show me a regular TextBox and when I clicking on it, nothing happen...

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server"     TargetControlID="txtStartDate">
</asp:CalendarExtender>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using something like this (ScriptManager):

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="smContent" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

in your page, you shoudl replace it with something like this:

```
<AjaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="smContent" runat="server" </AjaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

see more [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1923659.aspx?Using%20ScriptManager%20or%20ToolkitScriptManager%20with%20ASP%20NET%203%205%20AJAX%20Website)